# Error PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner::Error

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger, redmine

I have error with passenger.

I set up redmine in VPS. It run ok when I run in webrick. I used to passenger to run redmine on port 80.

path: usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf

```
 LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
 PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
 PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17

 PassengerMaxPoolSize 2
 PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 2
 PassengerPoolIdleTime 100


 <VirtualHost 112.78.6.191:80>
    ServerName projects.gzerone.com
    ServerAlias www.projects.gzerone.com
    DocumentRoot /home/gzerone/public_html/redmine-2.1.2/public
RailsEnv production
     #ErrorLog /usr/local/apache/logs/redmine.error.log
#RackBaseURI /rails
     ServerAdmin webmaster@projects.gzerone.com
     #UseCanonicalName Off
    #CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/projects.gzerone.com combined
    #CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/projects.gzerone.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
     ## User gzerone # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
<Directory /home/gzerone/public_html/redmine-2.1.2/public>
    #AllowOverride all
     Allow from all
    # MultiViews must be turned off.
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup gzerone gzerone
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup gzerone gzerone
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RUidGid gzerone gzerone
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/gzerone/public_html/redmine-2.1.2/public/cgi-bin/


# To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/gzerone/projects.gzerone.com/*.conf"
```

[image]

In error_log of apache:

```
[ pid=23984 thr=23634338875820 file=utils.rb:176 time=2012-11-23 10:39:34.067 ]: *** Exception Errno::ENOMEM in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Cannot allocate memory - fork(2)) (process 23984, thread #<Thread:0x2afd98bf1358>):
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:462:in `fork'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:462:in `safe_fork'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

I hope. You give any suggestion to fix it.

Comment: Thank Tass. The frist I thought like you. But I checked memory I run it. I always have 600->700 MB free memory

Comment: Maybe it's running out of threads? `thr=23634338875820`

Comment: Yes. can you give me some suggestions to fix it. please explain me about error.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the logs, the ApplicationSpawner is crashing because of an out-of-memory errors. You don't have enough memory.

There are several things you can do:

- Use conservative spawning so that you don't have an ApplicationSpawner process. Since your pool size is only 2, using an ApplicationSpawner does not bring you any advantages.
- Add more swap space.
- Upgrade your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, I believe it has something to do with Passengers control and optimizations options such as PassengerMaxPoolSize. You might need to set it higher than 2. I noticed the error occurred the first time someone viewed my application on another computer synchronously.

To quick fix, try going into the project directory and rebundle the app by `bundle install` then restart the web server, `sudo service httpd restart` this should reset Passenger.

Also, a missing `config.ru` file resulted in the same error message. You might want to check out the discussion [here](http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/e5c7495a6fef4ba7).

Wish I could tell you WHY this happened, hopefully someone will. I'd love to understand the exact problem mysef, to fix permanently.